# Views Megarows - Strange resizing in Internet Explorer

Tags: views, theming

Recently I've encountered a strange error with using [views megarows](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_megarow) and internet explorer. If I click the link that displays the megarow content, in IE at least all of the sudden the webpage has lost half the browser window area. This is only being seen in IE, and not Chrome or Firefox.

I'm not sure what could be causing it. Here is a link to a screenshot of the visual error.

[image]

Any assistence in this would be appreciated, even if it is what to disable or enable.

Comment: IE might be cancelling your `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` when the JQuery is fired, check your CSS and see what happens if you set them to !important.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. I've also noticed that the view megarow when I click on it in IE is in fact making the tabs I have created through views disappearing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a bug in the existing module, and it should be discussed in the issue queue on the project page of the module on drupal.org and not here.

Comment: BUt is it a bug or is it a css problem?

Comment: The 2 things are not mutually exclusive.  If you are testing with a default theme as suggested by the screen shot then I'd suggest that it's a module bug with the CSS and belongs in the issue queue.  If you have got theme modifications what happens if you revert to plain garland?

Comment: actually if I turn on a base zen theme in IE everything looks just fine when I use the megarows.